Rebooting Windows10 after installing ubuntu as dual boot while windows was accidentally on hibernate and windows repair confusing C: and D:
I have installed ubuntu as a dual boot alongside an existing Windows 10 installation. Now I cannot boot windows. Windows was first on Drive C: (1TB SSD) and I installed Ubuntu onto D: (also 1TB SSD) where I also removed an old Ubuntu installation in the process. Now Windows won't boot. Apparently I installed it while I put Windows on hibernate instead of shutting it down, which is likely because I am working on a laptop with a broken battery that has a life of only a few minutes.
When I go into the BIOS into boot options, I see a toggle within bootloader where both the windows and Ubuntu bootloaders are shown. When I put Windows first, it tries to boot, shows "SYSTEM RESET" on the attempt and then boots ubuntu, switching the boot order again in the BIOS (ubuntu first).
I tried Ubuntu boot repair as explained in the most upvoted answer here, as well as Windows boot repair in Option 1 here. Interestingly the Windows boot repair showed it detected a Windows installation on D:, not on C: (which is the drives swapped to how they were before installing Ubuntu). I can for sure say they are swapped, because the files are still accessible from Ubuntu when mounting the other drive, so I did install ubuntu on what was D:.
And the second observation: Ubuntu refused to mount the drive in anything else than readonly because it detected windows in hiberation on that partition.
How do I get Windows back?
Update: Bootinfo summary report is here. here. It seems there's a Windows recognized in the MBR on both physical drives.

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  If partition D: drive is now Ubuntu, Windows will  not be able to see it. Windows does not know about Linux partitions.

Added Bootinfo summary to the post

Link not working to pastebin.

LInk now working. You show Windows UEFI entry booting from ESP on sda1. See line 71 which is same ESP as Ubuntu is using. But sda1 shows no Windows UEFI boot files. it should have a /EFI/Microsoft folder with boot files. You can only fix that with a Windows repair/recovery flash drive. Boot-Repair thinks you have Legacy/BIOS install since that folder missing in ESP. But since drive is gpt, Windows must be UEFI.

I think this is because Windows is on nvme0n1p2, not sda1. nvme0n1p2 maps to C: on the Windows OS. I tried Windows recovery from a Win10 stick, but it didn't fix the issue. Should I perhaps remove the Windows entry on sda1?

This does not sound like an Ubuntu problem but a Windows installation issue.

Not sure how you got Windows on NVMe drive with its boot files in the ESP on sda. You have no ESP on NVMe drive. And Windows bootloaders in MBR is an error as installs are on gpt drives and can only be UEFI boot. Boot loaders in MBR are only for BIOS installs on MBR partitioned drives, normal prior to 2012.

Update: Because this is my secondary machine and I got all data secured, I decided to just clean reinstall everything.
